# React Native: Android native module emit event after MainActivity is started

Tags: android, react-native

I'm writing an NPM module to emit an event from native code after the MainActivity is started, so that I'll be able to add a listener in `componentWillMount()` and do the things I want. I can write the listener code somewhere else but I want to access the `props` of the component.

I'm sending the event right after `startActivity` call, as the `startActivity` call is asynchronous it immediately sends the event even before the component from JS part is initialized. So, I'm not able to listen for the event.

Ultimately, I want to wait till the `MainActivity` is started so that the listener will be added then it'll be safe for me to emit event from native code.

Any ideas or pointers how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to finally achieve what I wanted. I defined a public static function in my native module file and called it from `onCreate` function of my app's `MainActivity.java`.

I successfully published the module to NPM...:D

https://github.com/vicke4/react-native-invoke-app